# My post was edited by review process. What's a poster to do?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

My post https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13566312 was just rendered incomprehensible by your editing process.  In spite of one reviewer, @Christian_Ternus voting against the change with very cogent arguments, the rest of the "review squad" appears to have gone along with the change, as if on auto-pilot, without explaining anything about why.  Neither has the original suggester of the edit provided any explanation for the totally unneeded and harmful change.

My original post correctly mentioned in the title, that the problem was one of display.  The edited post hides this critical point and thereby makes this issue much harder to find as Mr. Ternus indicated.  I have since developed a workaround for the problem, but I don't want to share my findings with Stack Overflow unless they undo the edit they have done to my poor post!

This arrogant and unthinking behavior by Stack Overflow reviewers is maddening.

Comment: @Tushar The edit changes the question being asked from why a window is missing to why a plugin isn't available. The edit is wrong.

Comment: you are right, people robo-review edits and a lot of crap that shouldn't pass, passes.... but the system provides you with the tool to revert that...  (oh and no need for that much hyperbole in your posts)

Comment: _"incomprehensible "_, _"out-of-control"_, _"violence"_, _"arrogant"_, _"unthinking"_... Don't you think you're exaggerating just a bit?

Comment: Basically: If you disagree with an edit made to a Q/A of yours, just roll it back. It's simple, really.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the hyperbole, didn't realize I could revert the edit.

Answer (score 17):

While I think "violence" is a bit hyperbolic, you have the option (and power) to roll back any edit so that it points to a different revision.

You may find the list of revisions for this post [at this location](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38399857/revisions).  I've already rolled back the title edit.

Comment: Interestingly, by calling attention to this, I seem to have stimulated a number of new downvotes on the original post - none of them explained and all of them anonymous.  This sort of retaliatory behavior on a post that is more than two months old is another annoying "feature" of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SteveCohen:  Seriously, enough with the hyperbole.  It's just not that deep.  Relax about the votes as well; if the system detects serial voting, it will be rolled back within about a day.

Comment: It's an annoyance, that's all.  Soon I will forget about it.  But it is a (minor) problem.  On the whole I get more positive than negative from Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SteveCohen so, what happened there is that you linked a post on Meta. Meta has the visitors who care the MOST about quality on the site. Your put a spotlight to your question. A lot of people will be visiting your link and voting appropriately on it. Check for "meta effect" for more info.

Comment: @Patrice Steve also said "if I don't get my way I am going to keep my ball to myself"....

Comment: @Ramhound and that relates to me explaining the meta effect how?